# Checking a file for a specific IP address?

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is check a file named `ip-addresses.php` in the same directory for a specific IP address and if the IP is **NOT** in the file then I want to assign the value of `spark`

Here is what I have so far:

```
$ip = 


if( $ip ) {
    $value = "spark";
}
?>
```

So what I'm trying to do is have the value `$ip` check the php file for some IPs and then assign the value of "spark"

How do I do this?

Comment: Is `ip-addresses.php` generating a list or it *is* a list?

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` ?

Comment: @Havenard it is a list that i will add IPs to overtime

Comment: @folibis still very new to PHP so I don't understand sorry

Comment: `$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` - to get IP address of the script

Comment: You're storing a text-based(assumed from you comments) list in a php file?

Comment: @ElefantPhace im not sure what kind of file is best.. i just want to check if the person visiting the page has an IP that is in the list of IPs.. if the users IP matches one in the list i want to assign the value `spark`

Answer (score 3):

The function `file()` reads lines of a file as an array, making it easy to check for existing elements with `in_array()`.

```
$list = file("ip-addresses.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $list))
{
    $value = "spark";
}
```

Comment: if the IP is 127.0.0.1 do i simply just add 127.0.0.1 to the file `ip-addresses.txt` in the same directory? confused why `$ip` is defined here could you help me understand?

Comment: Well you want to check if an element exists in a list, if you want to check if an element exist in a list you must know what element it is, right? Otherwise what will you be looking for? That being said you must know what IP you want to verify that is or not in the list.

Comment: If you want to check if the *user's* IP is in the list, change `$ip` for `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: yes i want to check if the user that is visiting the page is in the list so which `$ip` would I change?

Comment: so now I can just create a text file with 1 IP per row and it will check to see if the users IP matches an IP in the list?

Comment: Exactly. One IP per line

Answer (score 0):

You need to read in the file first (if it is a php file you could also just create a function that returns an array for IPs and call it directly. Then look for the specific ip in the generated array (would be generated from reading the file) and if it is false set the ip to "spark".

```
// if you want to create another function in another .php file
include_once('ip-addresses.php');
$ip_array = get_ip_list();

// if you want the ips in a newline line separated .txt file
$ip_array = file('ip-addresses.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$ip = '127.0.0.1'; // theres no place like 127.0.0.1 but you can change this to what you want

if (!in_array($ip, $ip_array)) {
    $ip = 'spark';
}
```

Comment: could you explani how this works? i see a .php and a .txt file

Comment: @JoeBobby Choose one of the two implementations. One option is you store the ips to check against in a .txt file (probably better). The other is to create a .php file which has a function that returns those ips.